# Как переподключиться к websocket?

Tags: c#, websocket

Есть клиент websocket на c#. Он полноценно работает, в отдельных потоках крутятся методы получения данных, но через 3-4 часа сервер по каким-то причинам закрывает сокет. Вопрос как переподключиться к нему?

Попробовал отлавливать через try catch, но когда отваливается один сокек, то нормально происходит переподключение, а когда отваливается больше, программа зависает без ошибок.

Вызов:

```
Parallel.ForEach(pairs, pair => { new Thread(() => GetData("depth", pair)).Start(); });
```

Код Getdata:

```
private async Task GetData(string req, string pair)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = cancelTokenSource.Token;
        var client = new ClientWebSocket();

        await client.ConnectAsync(new Uri(webSocketUri), token);
        if (req.Equals("depth"))
        {
            string sym1 = getsym1(pair);
            string sym2 = getsym2(pair);
            Start_depth:
            try
            {
                await client.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"event\":\"sub\",\"params\":{\"channel\":\"market_" + pair + "_depth_step0\",\"cb_id\":\"" + pair + "\",\"asks\":1,\"bids\":1}}")), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, token);
                await Receiving(client, token, req, sym1, sym2);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                textBox3.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate ()
                {
                    textBox3.AppendText("Переподключаемся к websocket'у: " + pair + "\r\n");
                });
                goto Start_depth;
            }
        }
    }
```

Код получения данных:

```
private static async Task Receiving(ClientWebSocket client, CancellationToken token, string req, string sym1, string sym2)
    {

        var buffer1 = new byte[8192];
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[8192]);
        if (req.Equals("depth"))
        {
            const string pattern = @"\[\[(.*?)\]";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            string ask;
            string bid;
            string text;
            string[] asks;
            string[] bids;
            List<string> _ask = new List<string> { "", "" };
            List<string> _bid = new List<string> { "", "" };
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();


            while (true)
            {
                await client.ReceiveAsync(buffer, token);

                buffer1 = DecompressZLibRaw(buffer.Array);
                text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer1, 0, buffer1.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + text);
                if (text.Contains("event_rep"))
                {
                    var match = regex.Matches(text);
                    ask = match[0].Groups[1].Value;
                    bid = match[1].Groups[1].Value;
                    asks = ask.Split(',');
                    bids = bid.Split(',');
                    _ask[0] = asks[0];
                    _ask[1] = asks[1];
                    _bid[0] = bids[0];
                    _bid[1] = bids[1];
                    if (graph.ContainsKey(sym1))
                    {

                        graph[sym1][sym2] = _bid;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        graph.Add(sym1, new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
                        graph[sym1].Add(sym2, _bid);
                    }

                    if (graph.ContainsKey(sym2))
                    {
                        graph[sym2][sym1] = _ask;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        graph.Add(sym2, new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
                        graph[sym2].Add(sym1, _ask);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + text);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Аж слеза навернулась. Это действительно "Слепили из того что было" и `goto` и `Task` вперемешку с `Thread` и регулярки и `Invoke`, одним словом - жуть! По поводу проблемы, вы пробовали отладку проводить кода? Смотреть например где у вас "зависает" и почему? Может у вас например `goto` бесконечно начинает крутить? И почему вы говорите про "переподключение", а сами делаете `.SendAsync()`, а не повторный `.ConnectAsync()`, ведь `Send` - отправка запроса через открытое соединение, как вы его отправите через разорванное соединение, куда?

Comment: Вполне здравое логичное замечание. Сейчас поправлю, часа через три посмотрю на результат. Спасибо

Comment: Поставил метку после  var client = new ClientWebSocket();
Однако программа теперь не выдает никаких ошибок, однако данные по сокету не идут